# Как составить условие - результат за несколько месяцев по состоянию на заданный день месяца?

Tags: sql, oracle

Необходимо получить количество строк за 3-и последних месяца. Количество в каждом месяце до дня равного сегодняшнему дню. Например, если сегодня 24.08, то с 1-го по 24-е каждого месяца.

Пример ожидаемого результата:

```
Июнь   | 1000
Июль   | 800
Август | 900
```

Где: Июнь - с 1.06 по 24.06, Июль - с 1.07 по 24.07, Август - 1.08 по тек. дату (24.08).

Comment: А каков собственно вопрос?

Comment: @0xdb Как написать условие WHERE , чтобы вывести нужный результат?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Например, вот так:

```
with t (qty, dt) as (
    select 10, date'2015-01-01'+level-1 
    from dual connect by level<=3650 
)
select to_char (trunc (dt, 'mm'), 'Mon') month, count (*) count, sum (qty) sum 
from t
where dt between add_months (sysdate, -3) and sysdate
and extract (day from dt) <= extract (day from sysdate) 
group by trunc (dt, 'mm')
order by trunc (dt, 'mm')
/
```

Результат:

```
MONTH             COUNT        SUM
------------ ---------- ----------
Jun                  24        240
Jul                  24        240
Aug                  24        240
```

Comment: Нашел другой вариант написания условия **WHERE**
    ```
with t (qty, dt) as (    
  select 10, date'2020-08-01'+level-1    
  from dual connect by level<=60  
)  
select to_char (trunc (dt, 'mm'), 'Mon') month, count (*) count, sum (qty) sum   
from t  
where  
 **to_number(to_char(dt, 'dd')) <= to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'dd'))**  
group by trunc (dt, 'mm')  
order by trunc (dt, 'mm')
```

Comment: Да я знаю такой.  `to_number(to_char(dt, 'dd'))` два преобразования типов, вместо одного (преобразование в char довольно затратно). И `extract (day from dt)` гораздо легче читается, почти по русски: "Ну ка дай мне только день из этой даты".